# Is there a whitelist for Adblock Plus of well behaved sites?

Tags: ads

I don't mind text ads, or Reddit's advertisements where I can comment on them, and I should probably be supporting the sites I visit.

Is there a subscription that automatically whitelists good sites?

The closest I've found is "EasyList without element hiding". As it stands I'm whitelisting the ads manually from well behaved sites.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a browser add-on

Answer (score 1):

The newer versions of AdBlock Plus come with a [default whitelist](http://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads) of preapproved sites, than you have to turn off if you want to block **all** ads - this even led to people forking the extension for 'betraying' users etc.

From what I read, the sites have to apply for whitelisting - if your favorite sites don't do that, I'm not sure if there are other subs that allow you to easily whitelist an entire type of ads (like your Reddit example).